# remove extracting files after extract, split files

Tags: linux, bash, split, gzip, tar

I have a request and a problem.
I have archived files

```
tar xvpf /to_arch |gzip - c | split -b10000m - /arch/to_arch.gz_
```

I use this comand. this is archive got my system and i need move it on other server. 
on nev server i havent space for put arhive and extract it then i have idea.
Can someone help me write script in bash who can remuve extracted files.
like to_arch.gz_aa to_arch.gz_abto_arch.gz_acto_arch.gz_ad etc.
if finish extract aa file then script delete it.

```
cat *.gz* | tar zxvf - -i
```

Normaly i extract that but havent space on disk.

Comment: Could you please give some more clarity. Do you want to delete extracted files? If yes then why extract in first place ?

Comment: No, I want to delete the archive after unpacking.
I have 10 archives * gz_aa - * gz_aj. I have to use 'cat' to connect and unpack.
At the moment when the * gz_aa archive will unpack and begin to unpack the * gz_bb archive, I would like to delete the * gz_aa archive and similarly. to free space for the unzipped files.

Comment: Is it even possible?